# I can't print search result to MS Word

Tags: php, mysql, search, printing

I'm trying to print a search result to MS Word.

It is not working instead it displays in the same html page.

Here is my code:

viewstucon.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("configsample.php");
?>
<?php 
//Asuume that an ExportToWord input button is clicked.
if(isset($_POST["ExportToWord"]))
{
HEADER("Content-Type: application/msword");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=database_dump.doc");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");


if ($_REQUEST["course"]<>'') {
$search_course = " AND restu_course='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["course"])."'";
}

if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year BETWEEN '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_course;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_course;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_course;
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_id>0".$search_course;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
{
echo '<tr style="font:normal 12px Tahoma; color:#333333;">
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_title'].'</a></td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_year'].'</td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_by'].'</td>
</tr>';
}
}
?>
<html>
<title>Home</title>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Flat Login Form</title>
</head>

<body>


<form class="login-form" method="post" action="viewstucon.php">
<select class="s" id="course" name="course">
<option value="">Select Course</option>
<option value="Bachelor of Secondary Education"<?php if (!(strcmp("Bachelor of Secondary Education", $_POST["course"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Bachelor of Secondary Education</option>
<option value="Bachelor of Science in Automotive Technology"<?php if (!(strcmp("Bachelor of Science in Automotive Technology", $_POST["course"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Bachelor of Science in Automotive Technology</option>
<option value="Bachelor of Science in Electrical Technology"<?php if (!(strcmp("Bachelor of Science in Electrical Technology", $_POST["course"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Bachelor of Science in Electrical Technology</option>
</select>
<input class="sy" name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" width="100%" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" placeholder="From"/>
<input class="sy" name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" width="100%" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["to"]; ?>" placeholder="To"/>
<button type="submit" name="submit" >Filter</button>
<input type="submit" name="ExportToWord" value = "Export to Word" />
</form>

<table width="100%" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #999999; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0 auto; background:#ffffff; border-radius:20px;">
<tr style="background:#3366cc; color:#ffffff; font:normal 15px Tahoma; height:40px;">
<th>Research Title</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Proponent(s)</th>
</tr>
<?php
//Asuume that an Filter input button is clicked.
if ($_REQUEST["course"]<>'') {
$search_course = " AND restu_course='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["course"])."'";
}
if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year BETWEEN '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_course;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_course;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_course;
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE restu_id>0".$search_course;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
{
echo'<tr style="font:normal 12px Tahoma; color:#333333;">
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_title'].'</a></td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_year'].'</td>
<td style="padding:10px;">'.$row['restu_by'].'</td>
</tr>';
}
}else
{
echo'<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>';
}
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal example that demonstrates your issue. No one wants to dig through a wall of code like the one you posted.

Comment: I don't get that. Your headers claim that the response content is a MS-Word document. But the document you actually create and send is a html document. That won't work.

Comment: And that is my problem. I just want to print to MS-word only the result. I really don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear and your code is an formatted wall with no indenting. If you improve the quality of your question then you will improve you chances of getting a quality answer.

Comment: You cannot "print to MS-Word". The MS-Word file format is a proprietary blob, undocumented, obfuscated. You cannot somehow simply write it. You need a special software for that. That software is called "MS-Word", actually. I suggest you think about using a file format that makes more sense...

Comment: I'm trying to make another php file for exporting the results to MS Word function. But my problem is transferring the result from main page to print.php.